# Python - Get the process id of an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work with different processes in Python, and I am having some difficulty getting the PID of a particular instance.

For example, I'm sending the mainCar instance in one class:

```
warehouse = Warehouse()
mainCar = Car().start()
warehouse.add(mainCar)
```

in the warehouse class, I'm reciving the mainCar variable and want to know its PID

How do I get the process id using the mainCar variable? I would be passing this variable to a different class and the process ID of this variable would be different to what os.getpid() give me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does Car().start() spawn a subprocess?

Comment: Instances of multiprocessing.Process have an attribute `pid`.  It's None before the process starts and has a value afterward.

Comment: "the process ID of this variable would be different to what os.getpid() give me": why would it be different? How do you know?

Comment: To the (potential) close voters: misunderstanding concepts isn't the same as being an unclear question. What the OP is asking is perfectly clear, even if is based on flawed logic. @ForeverLearning: I've left this comment because your question has one close vote for "Unclear what you're asking", and I disagree with that close reason. It would be helpful if you showed us exactly what code you believe is spawning a second process, but I still think your question is clear.

Comment: Thanks @skrrgwasme, I was genuinely asking if it was possible to get a process id based off an instance. I understand that its flawed logic now. In a multiprocessing situation, I assume multiprocessing.current_process().pid would be right answer.

Comment: @ForeverLearning Cool. I'm glad you have a better understanding now. I agree that `multiprocessing.current_process().pid()` would be the right way to go, assuming that what you want is for your currently executing code to be aware of the ID of the process it is executing in. The multiprocessing `Process` object only contains a `pid` attribute because it represents a currently executing process. For (almost) all other classes, the concepts of PID and object are completely orthogonal, and the PID the object belongs to depends entirely on which process it is executing within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding what's going on. Your question still doesn't make much sense, because objects have *no notion* of PID. Even if you used the multiprocessing module to spawn multiple processes and passed objects around with queues, there is no Python function that will tell you the PID of the process that created the object automatically.

You could add something like this to your classes to track originator PIDs:

```
class PID_Tracked(object):
    def __init__(self)
         self.originating_PID = os.getpid()
```

But unless you manually store this data, there is **zero** association between objects and the PID of the process that created them.

The one exception to all of this is if you're using the multiprocessing module. Some classes in that module will provide a PID to track the spawned processes. But nothing in your question indicates that you're using multiprocessing (at this time), so I've excluded a discussion of it.

Comment: Thanks @skrrgwasme, that answered my question! I understand the logic now. I thought there was a way to get the PID.